# Perl regex conditional matching

Tags: regex, perl

What can be a possible regex to match any of the following:

```
Eggs and Legs
```

```
Legs and Eggs
```

I can only think of the following regex:

```
(Eggs|Legs) and (Eggs|Legs)
```

But i want to avoid matching:

```
Eggs and Eggs
```

```
Legs and Legs
```

PS: Edited my solution to add parenthesis,

Comment: That regex doesn't even work, you probably meant `(Eggs|Legs) and (Eggs|Legs)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a capturing group and negative lookahead:

```
/(Eggs|Legs) and (?!\1)(?:Eggs|Legs)/
```

I.e. the first and the last word can be `Eggs` or `Legs`, but [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the first word (using `(...)`), and then make sure `and` isn't followed by that word (using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) (`(?!...)`) for whatever the first word was (`\1`)).

See it in action [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/nU3bF5/1).

Comment: @VineetDeoraj See the updated answer. Is that a good enough explanation? (The link to Regex 101 has details for each and every part of the regex.)

Answer (score 3):

This will capture both words surrounding `and` and will print them both unless the first captured word is the same as the second one:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my ($match1, $match2) = /(\w+) and (\w+)/;
        print "$match1\t$match2\n" unless $match1 eq $match2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex you can only think of is not correct: it misses some parentheses. It in fact matches any string containing `Eggs`, `Legs and Eggs`, or `Legs`.

The correct form would be

```
/(Eggs|Legs) and (Eggs|Legs)/
```

To make it work, just check that `$1 ne $2`.

Comment: Thanks. "ne" as mentioned in @Biffen answer?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj: `ne` as mentioned in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop), but both should work.

Comment: I was taking about how to implement ne with this example, similar to biffen's answer or you have some other thought on that?

Comment: @VineetDeoraj: Yes, just do `print if /(Eggs|Legs) and (Eggs|Legs)/ and $1 ne $2;`